# How to make the fields as editable and not editable based on the picklist field selected

Tags: lightning, page-layout

I have a requirement where i want display  the fields in a section as editable and non editable based on the picklist field(status) .

I have custom Filed status  when user select as N/A the fields in the section Discharge and Re admit shouldn't be editable . I am trying to use out of box functionality and achieve this any help on how could be achieved this in Lightning .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using just no-code options, there are two possibilities:

- use validation rule (the user can change the value while editing, but they won't be able to save the changes)
- use dynamic forms (you could display this field two times - one time as editable and one time as a read-only and set components (fields) visibility based on the other field value)

More details on dynamic forms here: https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-dynamic-forms-overview-deep-dive-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If this is a standard page layout in lightning, then you cannot achieve this.

You have to go for [lightning record form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation) to achieve this.
Use `onChange` handlers to add class dynamically to elements in DOM.